# Execute script on ipv6 prefix change

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, posix

How can I execute a script or program whenever my (world-routeable) IPv6 prefix changes?

If there is (currently) no easy way to do this, a pointer to the corresponding Posix system calls would be totally okay for me. I could code some C myself then. But currently I'm a bit lost on this issue.

**Background:** My ISP (consumer contract) only gives me a world-routeable IPv6 prefix with a lifetime of about a day. There are some good reasons to do so (make network relocations possible) but my ISP (in contrast to my old one) does not simply re-assign my old prefix to me after its lifetime expired but gives me a completely new one. I now want to update some external DNS with my new prefix when that happens.

Comment: How are you currently configuring IPv6? Maybe there is a useful hook there.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271817/how-do-i-run-a-systemd-oneshot-service-whenever-my-system-gets-a-new-ipv6-addres/.

Answer (score 2):

You could sniff for SLAAC or DHCP6 packets to your MAC, for example, have iptables log particular bytes of SLAAC or DHCP6 to syslog and run a log watcher. There is no posix call to directly get local address, [though workarounds exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8645922/436063). For linux, [this netlink code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353441/436063) should let you wait for an update message from the kernel and perform whatever necessary steps you need.

Comment: Sniffing packets would require root privileges, right? I don't think that this should be necessary. The netlink code looks promising. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does. In my example, iptables runs in the kernel (privileged) but syslog should be world-readable. I can't guarantee  that particular netlink code does not require CAP_NET_ADMIN, as I haven't tried it, but it reasonably should not.

Comment: @MBober No, packet sniffing does not require root privileges. It *does* however require the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability, which root privileges grant you. [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution.... simple but works... just put this or something like this into /etc/cron.hourly:

```
#!/bin/bash
#


ADDRSTORE=/var/local/lib/dyndns/myoldipv6address

MYV6=`ip -6 address show scope global -deprecated | grep inet6 | cut -d/ -f1 | sed -e 's/ *inet6 //'`

MYOLDV6=`cat $ADDRSTORE`

if [ $MYV6 != $MYOLDV6 ]; then
  # do change-action here
  echo $MYV6 >$ADDRSTORE
fi
```